# Inkscape File recovery

Tags: 14.04, inkscape, png, svg

I was working on Inkscape software and saved my file as .png, after that my laptop suddenly stopped working. I restarted the system (hoping there will be a recovery file as inkscape .svg) but there wasn't. Is there any possibility I can get my file via that .png extension or is there any other solution or backup? I need my file layers back.

Comment: I can sympathize with you, now, because I have put a few yours on a drawing, saved it as PNG a few times and actually did click on "File > Save" as well (I had opened the SVG from an existing file). When I finally closed Inkscape, it asked if I wanted to save my document as "PNG", I said "no" and the program closed. Well, it never saved any SVG and I am left only with PNG rendered files and the original SVG. Dammit.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG is a bitmap export and does not contain any "vector" information about layers, paths, nodes, etc. There is no way whatsoever to get this kind of information back from the PNG.

If your laptop stopped working altogether, probably Inkscape has not been able to do an Emergency save (since it didn't crash strictly speaking, your system as a whole went down).

Concerning Auto Save and Emergency save:

> 1) When Inkscape crashes, it tries to save the current state in an
>   emergency save file and notifies the user in a popup dialog about its
>   file name and location if it succeeds. There might be occasions
>   (getting rarer with more recent versions of Inkscape) where due to the
>   nature of the crash the emergency save fails.
>
> The location and file name of the emergency-saved file depends on
>   whether the file has been saved earlier, and to some extend on the OS:
>
> - For unsaved files, the base name of the emergency file is 'New Document' (or the localized version of it). At the end of this base
>     name, a date and time stamp is added, as well as the suffix ".svg".
>     The location for emergency saves of unsaved files is $HOME on Linux
>     and OS X, and %UserProfile% on Windows (actual location varies
>     depending on Windows version and system configuration).
> - For files which have already been saved earlier, a date and time stamp is added to the original file name, and - if permissions allow -
>     the emergency save file is created in the same directory as the
>     original one which was currently edited.
> - If permissions prevent saving either in the current directory or in $HOME (or %UserProfile%), inkscape tries to save it in $TMPDIR.
>
> See also:
>   http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.graphics.inkscape.devel/34122/focus=34141
>
> 2) In addition to the emergency save mechanism, Inkscape has an
>   auto-save feature:
>   http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.47#Autosave
>   Note that this feature needs to be enabled and configured by the user
>   first (it is not enabled by default), and the directory specified in
>   the preferences dialog needs to exist (Inkscape does not create it
>   itself if missing).

(source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1177695)